# Channel form categories {category_parent} returns ID instead of name?

Tags: categories, channel-form

The the EE docs here: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/index.html#categories

It says the {category_parent} tag should show: "The name of the category parent if it exists, indented according to the category depth."

In fact, it outputs the parent's ID, not the name.

**Is this an error in the docs, or a bug in EE?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem I'm using the Cat2 addon to convert category id into something else (in my case url_title):

```
{categories}
     {if "{category_group_id}" == "12" && "{category_depth}" > 1}
          {exp:cat2:url_title category_id="{category_parent}"}
     {/if}
{/categories}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a bug, otherwise the variable would more logically be category_parent_id.